# Atmel studio does not work tool window for release or debug mode selection

Tags: visual-studio-debugging, atmel, atmelstudio, jtag, segger-jlink

I have recently been using Atmel studio 7.

I'll briefly explain my problem:
i can't get debugging to work because i can't select DEBUG mode. this is because when I enter `propreties -> tool` the set window does not appear but this message appears: `An Error trying to load the page. The type initializer for 'Atmel.VsIde.AvrStudio.Utils.MemoryPressureReliever' threw an exception.`

I use JTAG. Has anyone had the same problem as me?
Thanks to those who can help me!

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:
Here are the steps I took:

- I uninstalled the development environment
- deleted the information registered in the windows APPDATA folder
- Made Windows run all updates
- Reinstalled development environment

Honestly I did not understand if the problem was given by a windows update or by the development environment but the important thing is to solve...

Thanks to all the same**